# Simple Cucumber Test is not running on Sample Android Project

Tags: android, automated-tests, cucumber, android-testing

I am trying to run the simple cucumber test cases on Android Project, but it shows 0 test passed ,means it does not run test cases.

I have follow the project from this Github link :
https://github.com/emmasuzuki/CucumberEspressoDemo which works successfully on my machine.

But when I implement the same steps and files in my new Android Studio project then it says 0 Test Passed. I have attached my Android project github link. Could you please tell me the reason? Thank you for your consideration.

My GitHub Project URL which I am facing issue 0 Test Passed issue : https://github.com/Devsank/AndroidUiTesting

Answer (score 0):

You should have your instrumentation class under your test application package: `com.demouitesting.test.Instrumentation`. But your test instrumentation class was in `com.demouitesting.Instrumentation`.